# Is there an analogue of Mordell-Weil theorem for other fields?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The Mordell-Weil theorem states that for an abelian variety $A$ over a **number field** $K$ the group of $K$-rational points of $A$ is finitely generated and abelian.
What if $K$ is not a number field, e. g. **Q**$_p$ or a transcendental extension of $\mathbb Q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $K=\Bbb Q_p$ there will be uncountably many $K$-rational points.
The exact structure of $K$-rational points will depend on the
reduction type of the curve, but points close to the base-point $O$ are
in essence parameterised by the formal group of the curve. See Silverman's book for much more detail.

Comment: What is the group structure if the variety is an elliptic curve?

Comment: @FusRoDah Over finite extensions of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ if $|j|_p > 1$ then see the Tate curve, the elliptic curve stays isomorphic to a ($p$-adic) torus : $L^\times / q^\mathbb{Z}$ for some finite extension $L/\mathbf{Q}_p,q \in L^\times$. This is chapter V of *Silverman, Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*