# Generalisation of the Rank of an Abelian Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

If $A$ is an abelian variety over a number field $K$, then the set of $K$-rational points $A(K)$ is a finitely generated group by the Mordell-Weil Theorem. By the classification of finitely generated abelian groups, we know that there exists a free part of this group, whose rank we can call the rank of the abelian variety.

Consider now an abelian variety over lets say $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then the groups of $\mathbb{Q}_p$-points is not finitely generated anymore, see for instance ([Is there an analogue of Mordell-Weil theorem for other fields?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415689/is-there-an-analogue-of-mordell-weil-theorem-for-other-fields)). So there is no (naive) generalization of the notion of rank to such abelian varities.

However, maybe there is a non-naive generalization of the notion of rank (lets call it ``generalized rank"), which is backwards compatible, i.e. such that if $A$ is an abelian variety over a number field $K$ and $\nu$ is place of the number field, we have
$$\text{Mordell-Weil rank}(A)=\text{generalized rank}(A\times_K K_\nu)?$$
Possibly one would want this $\nu$ be such that $A$ has good reduction at $\nu$. One idea I had was to hope that the associated formal group law had a sensible analogue of a rank, however I don't see why and didn't find any reference to this in the literature.

Comment: Did you look at the $p$-adic analog of complex torus $ \Bbb{C}/(\Bbb{Z+\tau Z})\cong \Bbb{C}^*/\langle e^{2i\pi \tau }\rangle$  which is $ \Bbb{C}_p^*/\langle q\rangle$ with $q\in \Bbb{Q}_p^*, v(q)\ne 0$. It is an elliptic curve and its $\Bbb{Q}_p$-points don't seem to have a rank. Otherwise BSD conjecture says the rank is the vanishing order of $L(E/\Bbb{Q},s)$ at $s=1$, but its Euler product doesn't converge there so you can't relate that to $L(E/\Bbb{Q}_p,s)$. A last attempt would be to look at the $p$-adic modular form corresponding to $f, L(f,s)=L(E,s)$.

Comment: Surely not: there should be plenty of elliptic curves $E, E'$ with different ranks, such that $E, E'$ are isomorphic over $K_v$.

Comment: For example, take $E:y^2+y = x^3-x^2$ over $\mathbb Q$, which has rank $0$, and its quadratic twist $E':y^2  +y=x^3  +x^2  −16x−66$ which has rank $1$. These curves are non-isomorphic over $\mathbb Q$ but isomorphic over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$. So they will be isomorphic over $\mathbb Q_p$ for any prime $p$ that splits in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$.